live-in relationship
this question comes from curiosity.
Traditionally speaking, live in relationship doesn't exist before marriage in many places across many religions. i.e 2 people living a married life pre marriage ceremony, for us our pheras and so on.
my question is does this stem from scripture writings a.k.a. literature evidence or is it cultural norm word to mouth.

Live in relationship is described In the Bhagavata Purana as being one of the symptoms of Kali Yuga, so it is not based on the scriptures.
दाम्पत्येऽभिरुचिर्हेतुर्मायैव व्यावहारिके ।
स्त्रीत्वे पुंस्त्वे च हि रतिर्विप्रत्वे सूत्रमेव हि ॥ ३ ॥

dāmpatye ’bhirucir hetur
māyaiva vyāvahārike
strītve puṁstve ca hi ratir
vipratve sūtram eva hi


Men and women will live together merely because of superficial
attraction, and success in business will depend on deceit. Womanliness
and manliness will be judged according to one’s expertise in sex, and
a man will be known as a brāhmaṇa just by his wearing a thread.

This leads to varṇa-saṅkaraḥ (unwanted progeny) as explained by Arjuna in the first chapter of the Gita.
अधर्माभिभवात्कृष्ण प्रदुष्यन्ति कुलस्त्रियः ।
स्त्रीषु दुष्टासु वार्ष्णेय जायते वर्णसङ्करः ॥ ४० ॥

adharmābhibhavāt kṛṣṇa
praduṣyanti kula-striyaḥ
strīṣu duṣṭāsu vārṣṇeya
jāyate varṇa-saṅkaraḥ  


When irreligion is prominent in the family, O Kṛṣṇa, the women of the
family become polluted, and from the degradation of womanhood, O
descendant of Vṛṣṇi, comes unwanted progeny.

सङ्करो नरकायैव कुलघ्न‍ानां कुलस्य च ।
पतन्ति पितरो ह्येषां लुप्तपिण्डोदकक्रियाः ॥ ४१ ॥

saṅkaro narakāyaiva
kula-ghnānāṁ kulasya ca
patanti pitaro hy eṣāṁ
lupta-piṇḍodaka-kriyāḥ


An increase of unwanted population certainly causes hellish life both
for the family and for those who destroy the family tradition. The
ancestors of such corrupt families fall down, because the performances
for offering them food and water are entirely stopped.

दोषैरेतैः कुलघ्न‍ानां वर्णसङ्करकारकैः ।
उत्साद्यन्ते जातिधर्माः कुलधर्माश्च शाश्वताः ॥ ४२ ॥

doṣair etaiḥ kula-ghnānāṁ
varṇa-saṅkara-kārakaiḥ
utsādyante jāti-dharmāḥ
kula-dharmāś ca śāśvatāḥ


By the evil deeds of those who destroy the family tradition and thus
give rise to unwanted children, all kinds of community projects and
family welfare activities are devastated.

